# Domain Format for Add-on Domain on reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dns, recaptcha

I'm currently trying to integrate reCAPTCHA v3 to my newly created site's contact form.
The problem is that it always returns 'failed' response even though the input data were valid.
I tried add localhost to the domain list, and tested the site in my localhost, and it worked perfectly.

However, I do have my site on an add-on domain that's sit under my primary domain.
The question is how exactly do you add the add-on domain to the domain list?

i.e.

Primary domain : *mysite.net*

Add-on domain : *myaddondomain.com*

Do you just add *mysite.net*? Or just *myaddondomain.com*? Or *myaddondomain.mysite.net*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "addon" domain?  If your domain is `example.com` and you've defined a hostname like `something-else.example.com`, then you'd want to list both of these in your reCAPTCHA config.

Comment: Hi Brad. I'm not using sub-domain as per your example above. I have my site on a domain name that's an add-on to the primary domain. reCAPTCHA indeed stated that sub-domain should be included as 'subdomain.example.com in the list (which it still has the primary domain in the name). As in my case, it's a different domain but added to the primary domain. ([link](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/addon-domains)

Comment: What's the hostname in the URL that you're loading your site on?  That's what matters here.

Comment: The URL is myaddondomain.com. Though it refer to the same IP to its primary domain (mysite.net)

Comment: The IP address is irrelevant.  All that matters is the hostname on which the site is loaded.

Comment: In that case, I have that name in the domain list. But not working. Not sure what's causing it though. I thought it has something to do with the domain structure of the site.

Comment: What is the _full_ response you get in the verification step?